# Escape quotes in an iframe srcdoc value

Tags: html, iframe

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-srcdoc) quotes have to be escaped, i.e. instead of:

```
<iframe seamless sandbox srcdoc="<p>Yeah, you can see it <a href="/gallery?mode=cover&amp;page=1">in my gallery</a>."></iframe>
```

we should use:

```
<iframe seamless sandbox srcdoc="<p>Yeah, you can see it <a href=&quot;/gallery?mode=cover&amp;amp;page=1&quot;>in my gallery</a>."></iframe>
```

But isn't it OK to simply use single quotes in the above example:

```
<iframe seamless sandbox srcdoc="<p>Yeah, you can see it <a href='/gallery?mode=cover&amp;page=1'>in my gallery</a>."></iframe>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spec you linked to only notes that the quotes are escaped because

> otherwise the srcdoc attribute would end prematurely.

There is no issue using single quotes for the value as shown in your last example.

---

If there were single quotes inside the value (e.g., the word "you're"), then you'd have to escape either one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right.

We can use combination of double quotes and single quotes to escape from escaping them.

But the spec says :

> escape quotes // just quotes not specified whether single or double

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert from HTML to XHTML - [online tool cruto](http://www.cruto.com/resources/code-generators/code-converters/html-to-xhtml.asp)

```
     html:
<iframe seamless sandbox srcdoc="<p>Yeah, you can see it <a href="/gallery?mode=cover&amp;page=1">in my gallery</a>."></iframe>


 xhtml:
<iframe seamless="" sandbox="" srcdoc="&lt;p&gt;Yeah, you can see it &lt;a href=" gallery?mode="cover&amp;page=1&quot;">in my gallery&lt;/a&gt;."&gt;</iframe>
```

Comment: Does it still execute scripts within the embedded content?